# vba duplicates/empty cells -highlighting

Tags: excel, vba, colors, duplicates, highlight

I need to a create similar macro for duplicates (see below). The user will be able to choose a column symbol and then all the duplicates from the chosen column will be highlighted with color. I do not how to do that.

Below is the same idea but with empty cells.

Could you help?  THX!

```
Sub EmptyCells()

    Dim kol As String
    Dim ost As Long

    ost = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    kol = InputBox("Enter column symbol: B, C...etc.", "Column symbol", "B")

    If kol = vbNullString Then Exit Sub
    If IsNumeric(kol) Then
        MsgBox "You entered number, please enter column symbol", _
                vbInformation, "ERROR"
        Exit Sub
    End If
    If ost < 5 Then Exit Sub

    Range("A5:E" & ost).Interior.Color = xlNone

    Range(Cells(5, kol), Cells(ost, kol)).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).Select
    With Selection.Interior
        .Pattern = xlSolid
        .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
        .Color = 65535
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .PatternTintAndShade = 0
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Why not just use Excel's built in conditional formatting for highlighting duplicate values?

Answer (score 0):

Please make the following changes as per comments in your program. After changes it works for me. Assuming I have cleared existing formats on the worksheet and it is going to be first format condition.

```
Sub DuplicateCells() ' changed sub name

    Dim kol As String
    Dim ost As Long

    ost = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    kol = InputBox("Enter column symbol: B, C...etc.", "Column symbol", "B")

    If kol = vbNullString Then Exit Sub
    If IsNumeric(kol) Then
        MsgBox "You entered number, please enter column symbol", _
                vbInformation, "ERROR"
        Exit Sub
    End If
    If ost < 5 Then Exit Sub

    Range("A5:E" & ost).Interior.Color = xlNone

    Range(Cells(5, kol), Cells(ost, kol)).Select  ' Remove SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks)
    Selection.FormatConditions.AddUniqueValues   'Add this line
    Selection.FormatConditions(Selection.FormatConditions.Count).SetFirstPriority      'Add this line
    Selection.FormatConditions(1).DupeUnique = xlDuplicate   'Add this line

    With Selection.FormatConditions(1).Interior   '    add FormatConditions(1)
        .Pattern = xlSolid
        .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
        .Color = 65535
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .PatternTintAndShade = 0
    End With
    Selection.FormatConditions(1).StopIfTrue = False
End Sub
```

[image: duplicate values highlighted] Results on my sample data are shown.